# how can strips html tags in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

hi i am working on joomla. and i used the latest news module but it emerging a problem that the new display on page having the tags like paragraph

i wanna remove that tags from the news

my code  is

```
      <?php // no direct access
     defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); ?>

     <?php $i=1 ;?>
      <?php foreach ($list as $item):  ?>
     <?php if($i==1) {echo "<div class='latestnews_ttl'>       <p>".$item->cat_title."               </p></div>";} $i++; ?>
 <div class="news_box">
<p style=" padding:0px;"><strong><?php echo $item->text; ?> </strong></p>


<p><?php if(strlen($item->introtext)>100) 
                {
                    $txt =  str_split($item->introtext, 100);
                    echo $txt['0']."...";
            }
            else{
                    echo $item->introtext; 
            }
            ?></p>



            <div class='readmore'><a href="<?php echo $item->link;?>">read more</a></div></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It will give news with prefix tag "`<p>`" so please give the solution of it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Tried [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) ?

Answer (score 1):

Always remember in Joomla! never to modify core code, always overwrite the core templates by following the following guide [http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial_talk:Template_overrides](http://www.techportal.co.za/joomla/joomla-tutorials/124-how-to-modify-the-appearance-of-the-category-list-page-without-having-modifications-done-to-the-joomla-core-code)

[1](http://www.techportal.co.za/joomla/joomla-tutorials/124-how-to-modify-the-appearance-of-the-category-list-page-without-having-modifications-done-to-the-joomla-core-code): http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial_talk:Template_overrides or a quick how to http://www.techportal.co.za/joomla/joomla-tutorials/124-how-to-modify-the-appearance-of-the-category-list-page-without-having-modifications-done-to-the-joomla-core-code

If you do this in the core it will work, but once you may upgrade your changes could be gone.

Comment: This IS the way. Inside the template, files must be added in order to override the way content is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Since joomla is written in php you could use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)